# Push objects to new array with checked: true, if in mapped array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can I please get some help with this scenario?

1. An array of strings
2. A function that maps the array of strings and applies to each one of them a name, key and adds one more object "checked: false".
3. A function that takes the mapped array and transforms it according to the argument passed, storing the value in to another array and changing the "checked" to value "true"

Ex:

```
const defaultProducts = [
    "Laptop",
    "Tablet",
    "Phone",
    "Ram",
    "SSD",
    "RasberyPi",
    "Desktop",
    "TV",
    "Monitor"
  ];

const getDefaultProducts = () => {
return defaultProducts.map(products => {
    return {
    name: products,
    checked: false
    };
});
};

console.log(getDefaultProducts())

let forSale = []
function useProduct(product){
  if(product in getDefaultProducts()) {
    return{
      product: forSale.push(product), 
      checked: true
    };
  };
    return {product};
}

console.log(useProduct("Laptop"))
console.log(forSale)


returns 

[ { name: 'Laptop', checked: false },
  { name: 'Tablet', checked: false },
  { name: 'Phone', checked: false },
  { name: 'Ram', checked: false },
  { name: 'SSD', checked: false },
  { name: 'RasberyPi', checked: false },
  { name: 'Desktop', checked: false },
  { name: 'TV', checked: false },
  { name: 'Monitor', checked: false } ]
{ product: 'Laptop' }
[]
```

Should return:

```
[ { name: 'Laptop', checked: false },
  { name: 'Tablet', checked: false },
  { name: 'Phone', checked: false },
  { name: 'Ram', checked: false },
  { name: 'SSD', checked: false },
  { name: 'RasberyPi', checked: false },
  { name: 'Desktop', checked: false },
  { name: 'TV', checked: false },
  { name: 'Monitor', checked: false } ]
{ product: 'Laptop' }
[{name:"Laptop", checked: true}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
function useProduct(product){
  const found = getDefaultProducts().find(p => p.name === product)
  if (found) {
    found.checked = true
    forSale.push(found)
  }
  return {product}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help:
This is what I get
TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of undefined

Comment: Because you have to check if the product actually exists.

Comment: Thank you! Would you recommend a good source with array operations?

Comment: You can start here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 1):

In the part where you checked the condition as `if product in getDefaultProducts ()` will not work since getDefaultProducts is an array of objects. You are comparing strings with each object such as:

```
 "Laptop" === { name: "Laptop", checked: false }
```

which will return false always. Instead you can use find function:

```
function useProduct(product){
  getDefaultProducts().find(el => {
    if (el.name === product) {
      el.checked = true
      forSale.push(el)
    }
  });
  return product;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a nice aproach as well, less code. I would go for the solution above as the operation is stored in "found" constant. I think it is better to test, which I will start writing in a bit.